# Strange behaviour for function call in generic class

Tags: typescript

The following code compiles fine

```
interface W {
  x: string;
}
interface M {
  x: string;
}
type D<N extends M> = N | W;

declare function a<N extends M, Q extends D<N> = D<N>>(): Q | Q[] | undefined;
declare function b<N extends M, Q extends D<N> = D<N>>(p?: Q | Q[]): void;

const x = a();
b(x);
```

Things get interesting when I put function `b` inside a class:

```
export class C<N extends M, Q extends D<N>> {
  f(p?: Q | Q[]): void {}

  g() {
    const y = a();
    this.f(a());
    this.f(y);
  }
}
```

Here, `C.f` *should* be equivalent to function `b`. However, I get a type error on the line `this.f(y)`. Interestingly, the line `this.f(a())` compiles fine.

```
Argument of type 'W | M | (W | M)[] | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Q | Q[] | undefined'.
  Type 'W' is not assignable to type 'Q | Q[] | undefined'.
    Type 'W' is missing the following properties from type 'Q[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 28 more.
```

I don't understand this error, because type `Q` should be equivalent to `W | N` so how can `W` not be assignable to `Q`?

Comment: It's not quite equivalent, because the class has only one set of type parameters `N,Q`, whereas the two functions `a` and `b` have different type parameters (even though they have the same names).

Comment: That said, inspection shows that the actual type arguments for both `a` and `b` should be `<M, D<M>>`, so that shouldn't be the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is caused by having type parameters on a function, vs. type parameters on a class. To simplify the answer, I'll remove the `Q[]` option on `a`, `b` and `f` since the same behaviour is exhibited without it.

---

In the assignment `x = a()`, Typescript needs to infer a type for the variable `x`. This requires choosing concrete types for the type variables `N` and `Q`; in the absence of other constraints, their upper bounds are chosen, so `x` gets the type `M | W | undefined`. The important point here is that the compiler is free to choose the upper bound `D<M>` as the concrete type for `Q`.

Then, in the call `b(x)`, Typescript is equally free to choose `N = M` and `Q = D<M>`, so there is no type error.

---

In the class, the assignment `y = a()` is exactly as above, so `y` has the type `M | W | undefined`. However, then in the call to `f(y)`, Typescript is *not* free to choose `N = M` and `Q = D<M>`, because these `N` and `Q` are type parameters of the class. It is not sound here to infer `N = M` and `Q = D<M>`, because someone:

- could write `class M2 implements M { ... }` and create a `C<M2, D<M2>>` object.
- could write `type D2<N extends M> = D<N> & { ... }` and create a `C<M, D2<M>>` object.

So in the call `f(y)`, it is not safe to assign `y` of type `M | W | undefined` to `f`'s parameter of type `Q`, because e.g. when `Q = D<M2>`, or `Q = D2<M>`, or something else, then the variable `y` is not `Q` or a subtype of `Q`.

Comment: Ah, thanks. It was the error message that got me, removing `Q[]` as you suggested resulted in a far clearer error message.

This still doesn't explain (to me) why `this.f(a())` still compiles, though. Could you possibly elaborate?

Comment: Sure; in the expression `this.f(a())`, there *is* an additional constraint on the return type of `a()` imposed by the fact that it must be assignable to the parameter of `f`. `f`'s parameter is generally a subtype of `D<M>`, and `a` promises to return any subtype of `D<M>`, so it's allowed; the difference is that when you assign `y = a()` there is no extra constraint because `y` is a new variable, so the compiler just gives the upper bound of `a`'s return type which is `D<M>`.

Comment: An intuitive way to think of the function `a` is that it promises to return whatever subtype you ask it to return; in `this.f(a())` it returns the subtype needed to satisfy the parameter type `Q extends D<N>` for the object `this`. But in `const x = a();` it only returns `D<M>` because you didn't ask for anything more specific. The variable `x: D<M>` is then not specific enough to be used as an argument of `this.f`.

Comment: Oh, type is inferred because it's going directly into the function. The behaviour would be the same if I explicitly gave `y` a type. Duh! Thanks :)

Comment: Yes, or if you explicitly specified the type parameters for `a`, like `const y = a<N,Q>();`

Comment: As a side-note, the function `a` that you've defined, which promises to return any subtype you ask for, can't be implemented except by throwing an exception (or returning undefined, which its signature always allows). Consider a function like `guessWord<T extends string>(): T`, where `guessWord<'foo'>()` and `guessWord<'bar'>()` both compile to identical Javascript code but one promises to return `'foo'` and the other promises to return `'bar'`.